# Read json.gz file into pandas

Tags: json, gzip

I have a json.gz file that needs to be turned into a pandas dataframe.
I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_json('myfile.json.gz',lines=True,compression='gzip')
```

but my df looks like this:

```
Item
0   {'id': {'S': '83424'}, 'createdAt':...
1   {'id': {'S': '234324'}, 'createdAt'...
2   {'id': {'S': '234342'}, 'createdAt'...
```

Basically all my columns are in json format in one column. How can I counteract this?
I have also tried unzipping the file with:

```
with gzip.open("myfile.json.gz", "r") as f:
   data = f.read()
   j = json.loads (data.decode('utf-8'))
```

but get:

> TypeError: JSONDecoder.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'encoding'

Answer (score 2):

With the latest `pandas` version, you can directly load the `.json.gz` file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("myfile.json.gz", lines=True)
df
```

I'm using `pandas==2.0.1`